# Circular main in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

when i run "make" with the Makefile I wrote, it says "Circular main <- main dependency dropped." how to solve it?

```
main: main main.cpp pair.cpp
    g++ -o main main.cpp pair.cpp
generate:
    g++ -shared -fPIC -o libpair.so pair.cpp
clean:
    rm main.exe
```

Comment: Why do you have `main: main ...`?  Think about what that actually means to `make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main: main main.cpp pair.cpp
    g++ -o main main.cpp pair.cpp
```

There are too many `main`s in your makefile, make sure that you know the first `main` is the target name, and the second one is an executable that generated by "something else".

```
tar_main: main_exec main.cpp pair.cpp
    g++ -o main_exec main.cpp pair.cpp
```

Assume we modify your makefile as this to identify the two mains. Here, to generate the target `tar_main`, make requires `main.cpp`, `pair.cpp` and `main_exec`. But we have no `main_exec` yet and it can only generated by target `tar_main`...

So `tar_main` is waiting for someone to generate `main_exec` and provides to it, and `tar_main` can only be generated by `tar_main` itself, in your makefile. That's a dead-lock, and the cycle can be detected, make will refuse to run this.

Comment: Solution: delete `main_exec`, say modify your code as `main: main.cpp pair.cpp`